# php - infinite scroll load next results page xml

Tags: php, ajax, xml, scroll

I'm working on a website which fetch items from api in xml format.
I have created a php page to parse the xml api call, and accept a $pagenumber variable to fetch data accordingly. 
Here is the site link:
http://phantom-3.com/resindex2.php?u=Car-Parts-Wholesale

inside this page its calling 
    resindex-items.php?pagenumber=1 
which is the xml parsing script to display product results.

I would like to add infinite scroll to where on each scroll it fetch's each consecutive page.

```
resindex-items.php?pagenumber=1
resindex-items.php?pagenumber=2
resindex-items.php?pagenumber=3
```

Please forgive my ignorance, Ive been coding for about 1 month.

I understand that i have to use jquery and ajax to update a div. however I have no clue how to implement the actual code.

Comment: you might need some javascript or jquery plugins to make it happen. Just for reference visit this http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: This is a bit over  my head. is this for wordpress only?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear. But what you want is to use **Javascript**, so when you scroll down it'll fire an event to call an **Ajax** that would append in return to that **Div**.

Something like that should do the work.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
      .load('stuff.php',{},function(){
          $(this).append('<div id=\"text\"></div>");
       });
  }
});
```

Comment: would you happen to have an exmaple?

Comment: Thank you so much, im going to try it here in a second, however I have a question. How do i tell it to get stuff.php?page=2, page3 etc... on each consecutive scroll ?

Comment: it's difficult to answer that one and I have to give full implementation. try to check for XPath and probably http://www.php.net//manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php will help